# Password required every time I open a file

Tags: permissions, ecryptfs

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.01 from 14.04 but kept my home dir which was in an extra partition. After I recovered the ecryptfs data (had to re-add the passphrase to the keyring) everything seems to be fine. But when I open a text file now which is located in my home directory, an "authentication is required to perform file operations" appears, like I have no permissions for this file.

ls -l network.txt

shows me:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 niam niam 40 Mär 11  2016 network.txt
```

When I set ubuntu up, I've chosen the same username as before, niam.
My suggestion is that there might be a conflict. Any ideas?

**UPDATE **
Forgot to mention that when I looked at the properties of the file (right-click in nautilus) I realized that the parent folder was named: "admin///home/niam/".

Comment: Do you mean upgraded? If not, how exactly did you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I logged in today and checked the parent folder again it was "/home/niam/ like it should be. Very strage, but now, everything seems to work...